# VBA - If statement using sheet.name not behaving the way it should

Tags: vba, excel

I have some vba code which iis designed to be called from other subroutines  to lock spreadsheets unless the sheet name is equal to a set of strings which I define at the top of the sheet.

This if statement is not trigging as true.  What am I doing wrong here?

Code

```
Option Explicit

Const Password As String = "blah"
Const NonHideSheet1 As String = "Sheet1"
Const NonHideSheet2 As String = "Sheet2"
Const NonHideSheet3 As String = "Sheet3"
Const NonHideSheet4 As String = "Sheet4"
Const NonHideSheet5 As String = "Sheet5"

Public Sub Sheetlock()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim I As Long

Set WB = ThisWorkbook 

For I = 1 To WB.Sheets.Count

   Set Sheet = WB.Worksheets(I)
    If Sheet.Name = NonHideSheet1 Or _
       Sheet.Name = NonHideSheet2 Or _
       Sheet.Name = NonHideSheet3 Or _
       Sheet.Name = NonHideSheet4 Or _
       Sheet.Name = NonHideSheet5 Then
       GoTo nextbit '<-- skips over the sheets visible line but doesn't 
    End If

    If Sheet.Visible = True Then
       Sheet.Visible = False
    End If

nextbit:
Sheet.Protect (Password)
Next I

End sub
```

Comment: First thing is I would remove the Goto. The effect you want can be done using If...Then...Else. Then, step through the code using Debug and see whty the condition isn't triggered.

Comment: I've already stepped through and can see the string values match, I will try the suggestion of changing the goto line

Comment: Sorry @PootyToot. That code should work. I'd kill this question as this adds no value to the site. The issue has to be with something with workbook reference, capitalization of sheet names, or something missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong, but does this code do what you're seeking?

```
Public Sub Sheetlock()

  Dim WB As Workbook
  Dim Sheet As Worksheet

  Set WB = ThisWorkbook

  For Each Sheet In WB.Worksheets
    If Sheet.Name <> NonHideSheet1 And _
       Sheet.Name <> NonHideSheet2 And _
       Sheet.Name <> NonHideSheet3 And _
       Sheet.Name <> NonHideSheet4 And _
       Sheet.Name <> NonHideSheet5 Then

      Sheet.Visible = False
      Sheet.Protect (Password)
    Else
      Sheet.Visible = True
    End If
  Next Sheet
End Sub
```

My guess is the `goto` is the culprit.  I always try to avoid them -- not saying they are always bad, but in general if you can do it without a `goto` it prevents future confusion.

Comment: that did it, will remember this in the future, for some reason the goto command wasn't triggering properly so I rephrased the code to match your solution, it works!